# Refresh or invalidate the entire cache in eclipselink periodically

Tags: eclipselink

is there a way invalidate the entire cache in eclipselink periodically (say every 5mins).
can this be done in a property in the persistence.xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cache invalidation timeout on each entity,

See the @Cache annotation.

You could use a SessionCustomizer to iterate over all descriptors and set a default on all of them.

You could also use the JpaCache API at runtime to invalidate the entire cache.  You could use an EJB timer to call this.